# Rank of a Matrix and Echelon Form to determine ranks.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

What is the meaning **rank** of a matrix in terms of vectors, and how does **Echelon** form work in determining the rank of a matrix?

Comment: You have to convert the matrix to Echelon form in order to find the rank of a matrix

Comment: It's not like "You have to" but rather you can obtain (may be more easily) the rank of a matrix from its Echelon form.

Comment: Yes I agree with you

Answer (score 3):

The rank of a matrix is the dimension of the column space, or perhaps easier to understand, the number of linearly independent column (row) vectors.

Reducing the matrix to echelon form helps to determine the rank of the matrix: it is exactly the number of *non-zero* rows.

Answer (score 0):

The rank is the dimension of the column space (or the row space, it can be shown their dimensions are equal).

If you have the matrix in echelon form, then the rank is the number of "steps".